# Can't include <QtWidgets>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, include

I'm trying to link Qt5 in Visual Studio 15 2017.

I have added the paths and file references for additional (1) *include directories*, (2) *library directories* and (3) *dependencies* in the *Property Pages*.

I can include header files by refering to their path like this

```
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>
```

However, the [github project](https://github.com/bmpix/PolyVectorization/blob/master/src/mainwindow.cpp) I'm trying to build uses this line

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```

Visual Studio shows me an error on those lines

```
E1696   cannot open source file "QtWidgets"
```

When creating a solution from a `.pro` file using the *Qt VS Tools* in Visual Studio, I can include `<QtWidgets>`. But how can I include it in my existing project, which has not been created from a `.pro` file.

---

**Solution**
Placing a *MyProjectName.pro* file (with `QT += core gui widgets`) in the *MyProjectName* Folder and opening it with *Qt VS Tools > Open Qt Project File (.pro)* solves this problem. I can now include `<QtWidgets>`. But this doesn't seem like the correct way, given the VS gui.

Comment: The tutorial you linked is for Qt 4. With Qt 5 you'll need to add [`QT += widgets` to your .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669417/qt-5-3-qtwidgets-no-such-file-or-directory-include-qtwidgets).

Comment: Be careful, `#include <QtWidget>`, single, without s, not  QtWidgets.

Comment: `#include <QtWidgets>` is correct. (Just looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57158965/7478597) to confirm but have used it for sample codes many times before.) It works in Qt 5 for VS (with CMake project) as well as with Qt project files (if Qt widgets are enabled properly in both cases).

Comment: @S.M. No, `#include <QtWidgets>` is fine. There is a 's' because it includes the whole widgets module.

Comment: Why do you think your solution isn't correct? Qt project files are the Qt-ish way to provide some kind of portable build script. On Linux, the qmake tool produces a `Makefile` from it which can be used to build the executable with `make`. (With Qt VS Tools, I haven't any experience. I guess they provide a similar tool to prepare a VS project file out of a Qt project.) A subject of build scripts is the setup of appropriate include and library paths.

Comment: @Scheff I thought that the settings could all be done in the GUI of VS, since it provides a UI for linking libraries and making builds. If you think this is the answer, you can post it as such an I can accept it.

Comment: It's surely possible to do all the settings manually by UI. However, this might become tedious. I can imagine that Qt VS Tools can configure as well necessary defines and custom build steps (e.g. for Qt MOC). I once maintained VS projects manually (in a text editor) until we introduced CMake. (I wouldn't return ever...) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "QtWidgets" include file is a file in the "QtWidgets" directory. Your include path probably has something like "$(QTDIR)/include", but not "$(QTDIR)/include/QtWidgets". That's why your example with "QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h" works, but not just "QtWidgets" on its own.

Maybe it helps to look at the full path to the file you're trying to include (using my Qt 5.5.1 installation):

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets\QtWidgets
```

So if you have this in your include path:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include
```

That only gets you to the QtWidgets directory, but not to the QtWidgets file.

You also needs this in your include path:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets
```

Obviously, adjust this for your installed drive, Qt version, and MSVC version.

Comment: Adding `$(QTDIR)/include/QtWidgets` seems to be the solution. Thanks a lot.